# How to ignore first element with XPath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to grab only the text inside the `<p>` tag, but ignore the text inside the `<span>` tag:

```
<p class="pa">
<span class="">CONSELHO: </span>
     Insistir até que tudo esteja muito claro. Se você precisar de alguém para ajudá-lo no trabalho, peça especificamente.
</p>
```

My Xpath works fine when I test it directly in the browser, but in my code it doesn't work, see how I'm doing it:

```
text=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//p[@class='pa']/text()").text
```

Why doesn't it work?

How can I get the text inside the

tag and ignore the  tag?

Comment: try `test = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".pa > span:nth-child(2)").get_attribute("innerHTML")`

Comment: did not work friend